# What is the connection between QObject and a Cascade control

Tags: c++, qt, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

If we take a class such as "bb/cascades/Button" or "bb/cascades/Label" what connection does it have with QObjects? Are all core controls in cascade are also QObjects?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all controls in bb/cascades are sub-classed (eventually) from QObject. Most, but not all, Qt and Cascades classes are sub-classed from QObject.